# R - building a matrix from all iterations in a for-loop that gives a vector results

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I am running multiple simulations of sampling 20 individuals from villages.  I have a dataset with 2 columns, the first column being the village to which the observation belongs and the second column being 0 for a negative malaria test and 1 for a positive malaria test.  I would like to sample 20 people from each village, repeated 100 times.

I can get the sample to repeat, but I am having trouble taking the results from the loop and putting them into a matrix or data frame.  Here is the code I have so far.  Any help would be appreciated.  Other stacks have suggested creating the matrix beforehand and then adding the resultant vector, but I'm stuck as to how to add the vector.

At the end I would like a matrix with the positives vector as a column for each iteration of the loop.

> d = read.table("/Users/David/Documents/LQAS study/LQAS data.txt", sep=",", header=TRUE)
>
> head(d)
>     village500 malaria

1         22       0

2         22       0

3          1       1

4         20       0

5          1       0

6         19       0

> villages = split(d$malaria, d$village500)
>
> for(i in 1:100) {
>   +   sampled = lapply(villages, sample, 20)
>   +   positives = lapply(sampled, sum)
>   +   }

Comment: Ehm, what language/environment is this in?

Comment: R.  Sorry, new to the stacks - didn't know I needed to specify the program.

Comment: So next time please add the tag `R` to the posting. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a longhand way to do this, though it is definitely not ideal and having more than 100 simulations would be a bit exhausting.

```
villages = split(d$malaria, d$village500)

positives = vector("list", 100)

for(i in 1:100) {
    sampled = lapply(villages, sample, 20)
    positives[[i]] = lapply(sampled, sum)
    }

simulations = cbind(positives[[1]], positives[[2]], positives[[3]], positives[[4]], positives[[5]], positives[[6]], positives[[7]], positives[[8]], positives[[9]], positives[[10]], positives[[11]], positives[[12]], positives[[13]], positives[[14]], positives[[15]], positives[[16]], positives[[17]], positives[[18]], positives[[19]], positives[[20]], positives[[21]], positives[[22]], positives[[23]], positives[[24]], positives[[25]], positives[[26]], positives[[27]], positives[[28]], positives[[29]], positives[[30]], positives[[31]], positives[[32]], positives[[33]], positives[[34]], positives[[35]], positives[[36]], positives[[37]], positives[[38]], positives[[39]], positives[[40]], positives[[41]], positives[[42]], positives[[43]], positives[[44]], positives[[45]], positives[[46]], positives[[47]], positives[[48]], positives[[49]], positives[[50]], positives[[51]], positives[[52]], positives[[53]], positives[[54]], positives[[55]], positives[[56]], positives[[57]], positives[[58]], positives[[59]], positives[[60]], positives[[61]], positives[[62]], positives[[63]], positives[[64]], positives[[65]], positives[[66]], positives[[67]], positives[[68]], positives[[69]], positives[[70]], positives[[71]], positives[[72]], positives[[73]], positives[[74]], positives[[75]], positives[[76]], positives[[77]], positives[[78]], positives[[79]], positives[[80]], positives[[81]], positives[[82]], positives[[83]], positives[[84]], positives[[85]], positives[[86]], positives[[87]], positives[[88]], positives[[89]], positives[[90]], positives[[91]], positives[[92]], positives[[93]], positives[[94]], positives[[95]], positives[[96]], positives[[97]], positives[[98]], positives[[99]], positives[[100]])
```

Comment: You can just do `simulations <- do.call(cbind, a)`.